# Schema Change Script : Validation and test cases

Tags: sql, database, unit-testing, testing, deployment

I  have written a schema change script to remove a certain column C from Table A to Table B. 
This is my logic/algorithm,

1. If Column C does not exist already in Table B, add it.
2. If column C exists in Table B, update the newly added Column values(which would initially
   be null) to the corresponding matching values from Table A on a
   condition A.columnZ(Primary_Key) = B.ColumnZ(Foreign_key).
3. Drop Column C from Table A.

I have written the script for the same( a simple one, though). Now, since Database changes are highly critical because its going to be run on Production database and the column contains some values related to Users' billing information, I want to test them completely before going for deployment.

I would like to get **suggestions for Test-cases** to validate the script.Since, this is the first time we're going to making this scripts, any other advice on potential problems while making change scripts, would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) for testing database scripts. It's a very fine tool, but perhaps overly java centric. You can google for similar tools in other languages.

Personally I use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to manage all changes to my database schemas. It reduces much of the complexity of database migrations by putting the database in a known state. I don't have to test for conditions where a column may or may not exist, because, the entire schema is effectively under revision control. Database refactoring actions which are destructive to data, are always tricky to test. The real advantage of using a tool like liquibase is that it becomes trivial to setup production-like test systems.